# Where are transmission-cli download saved?

Tags: 20.04, transmission

I cannot find where my torrented folder is. I did `transmission-cli file.torrent` and it has finished.

Comment: Check your config file: `$HOME/.config/transmission-daemon` Where does it say completed downloads get saved to?

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu, partial and completed torrents are saved to `~/Downloads` by default. If you are not running Ubuntu, then your guess will be as good as mine ...

Comment: They get saved in the directory you told them to in the applications configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me in Arch Linux it was in:

```
/home/user/Downloads
```

I also found this command line option (from [documentation here](https://cli-ck.io/transmission-cli-user-guide/)), that was helpful in finding the download dir:

```
transmission-daemon --dump-settings
```

There was more than one page of output, I could make it scrollable with the command:

```
transmission-daemon --dump-settings 2>&1 | less
```

Answer (score 2):

The transmission-daemon defaults to `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads` however this can be overriden in the settings.